# Run script on Windows Container as administrator

Tags: windows, docker, privileges

I am writing a Dockerfile on top of `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore` which is supposed to run a script in administrator mode and then start CMD. The CMD shell should **not** be elevated. How do I achieve the same?

If I add `USER ContainerAdministrator` to my Dockerfile, the first script is run without any issues but the CMD shell is then elevated.

The other option might have been to use `USER ContainerAdministrator` and then spawn CMD with `runas /user:ContainerUser`, but runas needs password to be entered via a prompt (or using `/savecred` but that won't work here), so it's not possible either.

Thanks in advance!